# Selenium cannot find element in chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate some actions on a website. My script fills out a form and clicks post and then the website essentially asks if you are sure you want to post and you need to click the post button a second time. The problem is, while the old post button is no longer visible to the user, Selenium can only find the old post button and insists that the new post button does not exist.
Here is what the HTML looks like for the new post button.

```
<span id="__w2__w927tml1_submit_question_anon">
    <a class="modal_cancel modal action" href="#"
    id="__w2__w927tml1_add_original">Ask Original Question</a>
</span>
```

I have tried every different locator I can think of but it always locates the old post button. The closest I've got is locating the parent class shown above, but when trying to parse through its children it says there are none. I am at a loss for what to do here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post your Selenium code please?

Comment: Have you tried Xpath? Go to inspect element in the chrome, right click the element you are interested in. Go to Copy, and Copy Xpath. Then use the `find_element_by_xpath` method.

Comment: Try to import `WedDriverWait`,`By` and `ExpectedConditions`. Then try this code `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[.='Ask Original Question']"))).click()`